# NativeBase 2.0 - How to navigate in the Drawer component?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I recently tried using the Drawer component of Native Base 2.0 which basically has this template:

```
closeDrawer = () => {
  this.drawer._root.close()
};
openDrawer = () => {
  this.drawer._root.open()
};

render() {
  return (
    <Drawer
       ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
       content={<SideBar navigator={this._navigator} />}
       onClose={() => this.closeDrawer()} >

    <Content>
      insert content here
    </Content>
    </Drawer>
  )
}
```

I made my customer SideBar component with some ListItems in there, I made those list items clickable using the react-navigation package.

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data)}>
```

The problem is that I don't get the this._navigator property that is being passed from the Side Bar and I always get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeBase has deprecated Drawer, use react-navigation instead

Answer (score 1):

They have added back Drawer in v2.8.0

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/releases/tag/v2.8.0